# Is $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ such that functions $z\mapsto \sin (f(z))$ and $z\mapsto \cos (f(z))$ are holomorphic on the entire complex plane. 
 a) Is $f$ also holomorphic in $\mathbb C$? 
 b) If we additionally assume that $f$ is continuous, is $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb C$?

Logic suggests that in point a) the correct answer is NO, and in b) YES, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: You can pick a really dumb function for a counter example for (a). For example, let $f(z)=2\pi$ when $z=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Your guess is correct. The problem is that $\cos, \sin$ are $2\pi$-periodic, so you can pick $f$ jumping around, but taking values in $2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For $b.)$ it is useful to investigate where $\sin, \cos$ are local diffeos. Then you can locally invert them and obtain with the continuity assumption on $f$ that it holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already been told in the comments that the answer to the first question is negative.

Now, suppose that $f$ is continuous that both of those functions are holomorphic. Then so is$$z\mapsto\cos\bigl(f(z)\bigr)+i\sin\bigl(f(z)\bigr)=e^{if(z)}.$$Now, let $z_0\in\Bbb C$. Let $g(z)=e^{iz}$. Since $g$ is locally invertible (this follows from the fact that $g'$ has no zeros), there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f(z_0)$ such that its restriction to $V$ has an analytic inverse $h$. And, since $f$ is continuous, there is a neighborhood $W$ of $z_0$ such that $f(W)\subset V$. So, $f|_W$ is analytic, since it is equal to $h\circ e^{if}$ there.

Answer (score 0):

To show a is "no", just let $f$ be a non-constant function taking values only in $2\pi\mathbb{N}$, so that $\sin(f) =0$ and $\cos(f) = 1$, which are holomorphic, but since $f$ is not even continuous it is not holomorphic.

For b, not that if $f$ is continuous, then around some $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ we have by continuity that $f(z)$ can be made to stay in a small neighborhood of $f(z_0)$ by continuity. At least one of $\cos$ and $\sin$ has nonzero derivative at $f(z_0)$, so by the inverse function theorem either $\sin$ or $\cos$ is locally invertible around $f(z_0)$ with holomorphic inverse. (If you are not comfortable with inverse function theorem, then just note that all I am saying here is you can pick a branch of $\arcsin$ or $\arccos$ which are analytic near $\sin(f(z_0))$). Then we have either $f(z) = \sin^{-1}(\sin(f(z))$ or $f(z) = \cos^{-1}(\cos(f(z))$ is, being the composition of two holomorphic functions, holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$. Since $z_0$ is arbitrary, $f$ is holomorphic.